# Show that all $f$ integrable on $[0,1]$ with $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = 0$ is a vector space

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $V =$ the set of $~f$s integrable on $[0,1]$ with $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = 0$.

I want to show that it is closed under addition. Let $f$ and $g$ be in $V$. $f + g$ be in $V$. Then since the integral of $f$ and integral to $g$ both = $0$, then this shows that $V$ is closed under addition. Is this correct?

How do you show the existence of negatives? That is, $f(x) + $something$ = 0(x)$, where $0(x) = 0$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$. How do you show what the something is supposed to be.

Show that $a(b\times f(x)) = (ab)\times f(x)$, where $a,\ b,\ x$ in $R$. Do you show this by saying

$a\times (b\int_0^1f(x)) = 0 = (ab)\int_0^1f(x))$? Is this how it is done?

Comment: We have $\int_0^1 (-f(x))\,dx=-\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=0$.  Also, $\int_0^1 af(x)\,dx=a\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=0$. Other properties are checked in similar ways.

Comment: The integral of -f(x) = 0. So this shows what?

Comment: This shows that if $f(x)$ is in $V$, then $-f(x)$ is in $V$. That's part of showing $V$ is a vector space.

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is how to show these things. Why is it not enough to say that f(x) + -1*f(x) = 0.

Comment: I have written out a solution. Certainly $f(x)+(-f(x))=0$. But we need to show that $-f$ is in $V$. This follows quickly by the properties of integral from $f(x)+(-f(x))=0$, but probably needs to be pointed out explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have sketched a correct proof that $V$ is closed under addition. More explicitly, suppose that $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=0$ and $\int_0^1 g(x)=0$. Then the integral $\int_0^1 (f(x)+g(x))\,dx$ exists and is equal to $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx+\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx$, that is, $0$. Thus $f+g$ is in $V$.

We also want to show that $V$ is closed under the operation of additive inverse. It is easy to see that if $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=0$, then $\int_0^1 (-f(x))\,dx=-\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=0$. So if $f\in V$, then $-f\in V$.

We want to show also that $V$ is closed under multiplication by scalars, that is, that if $f\in V$, then $af\in V$ for any constant $a$. So we need to verify that $\int_0^1 (af(x))\,dx=0$. This is straightforward, since $\int_0^1 (af(x))\,dx=a\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$.

Closure conditions now have been verified. We also need in principle to check that various other algebraic conditions hold, such as $(a+b)f=af+bf$, and $a(bf)=(ab)f$. These hold for **all** functions, so in particular for elements of $V$.

Comment: It seems to me that we are showing properties about integral of functions. Not about functions, which is what we were asked.

Comment: It's the properties of integrals that show that this set of functions is closed in these ways.

Comment: To verify that $V$ is a vector space, we need to verify that it has certain closure properties. Since $V$ is defined as the set of functions whose integral over $[0,1]$ is $0$, our proof will have to use some basic properties of integrals. For example, the set of all functions $f(x)$ such that $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=17$ is not a vector space.

Comment: I'm sorry to be such a stickler, but isn't this what needs to be shown: that the $f$s in V have this properties, not that when we take the integral we get the right properties. It sounds like you are saying that a(bf) = ab(f) b/c the integral of f over [0,1] = 0 so you can trivially show a(b$\int$f) = ab($\int$ f). But you haven't shown that this property holds for the function itself.

Comment: We need to verify **closure**, that the sum of two functions in $V$ is in $V$, and that the product of a function in $V$ by a constant is in $V$. The **other** properties we need for a vector space have nothing to do with the integral being $0$, they are just basic algebraic properties that hold for all functions, such as $a(bf)=(ab)f$. I don't expect they need to be proved, though perhaps they should be mentioned. If you want to prove (and I don't think you are expected to), just say $a((bf)(x))=a(bf(x))=(ab)f(x)=((ab)f)(x)$.